# Accidentally created directory with period . character

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, special-characters

Don't ask how, but I've somehow created a directory name with a single period character (.) and, as that is a special character for directory navigation, I have no idea how to remove it!

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 admin admin    4096 Nov 30 14:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root  root     4096 May 18  2022 ../
-snipped output-
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin users    4096 Nov 30 14:10 ．/   <-- this one
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a period but another unicode symbol that looks similar. Try copy-pasting that after `rm`

Answer (score 5):

It's not the same dot as `.`, it's Unicode's *FULLWIDTH FULL STOP*. Just copy & paste the name to `rmdir`:

```
rmdir ．
```

Or use something that understands unicode names:

```
perl -e 'rmdir "\N{FULLWIDTH FULL STOP}" or die $!'
```